# How to use a search bar in Beautiful Soup 4 (Python)

Tags: python, web, input, beautifulsoup

I am making a dictonary application with the help of Beautiful Soup 4. I am using this website as the dictonary:

[LINE Dictionary](http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home)

Let's say, for example, I want to enter the word "Hello" into the search bar. How would you do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do *not* need bs4 to do this, you just need to observe the url and see what changes when you enter something in the search bar:

**Original:** `http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/home`

**Hello:** `http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/search?query=Hello`

**goodbye:** `http://ce.linedict.com/#/cnen/search?query=goodbye`

Then send a request to fetch it.

This will work because when you search in the search bar, it just sends a request to the server asking to match what you entered.

You can pass the request to the server directly by seeing what it will accept (in use normally with the search bar) and then mimicing this effect.

Comment: @BryanThai  No problem.  I suggest reading about GET and POST requests, I think they will really help you.

Comment: I will do just that :)